# Unexpected token = (with espree parser in module mode) in my react project using sonar-scanner

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am facing this error while using sonar-scanner.
It is unable to parse all those files in which i have used arrow functions.

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "antd";
import history from "src/components/history";

class BackButton extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    history.goBack();
    if (this.props.onBack) {
      this.props.onBack();
    }
  };
  render() {
    return <Button icon="arrow-left" onClick={this.handleClick} />;
  }
}

export default BackButton;
```

The error at line 6.
Need a solution to fix this.

Comment: have you enabled "transform-class-properties" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to use arrow functions inside a class you need to enable this plugin in your babel configuration.

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

or you can do it like this

```
class BackButton extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleClick = (val) => {
      ...
    };
    …
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any other solution to this as the earlier code also works fine and doesnt causes any problem.

Comment: you can do it without arrow functions.. if you are not using arrow functions then you can easily have class property and attach it to the instance in the constructor

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem isn't arrow functions, it's class fields. Your `handleClick` is a class field (basically a property declaration) using an arrow function as its initializer. The [class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) proposal is mature, but still at Stage 3, not actually in the spec yet (not even ES2020). In contrast, arrow functions have been in the language for over five years.

You'll need to be sure to enable support for class fields.

Comment: Can you please suggest me where should i make the changes?

Comment: If the problem is coming from Espree, it sounds like you need to update ESLint. Current versions of ESLint support class fields.

Comment: I upgraded ESLint but facing the same issue with sonar-scanner. It shows the same error. What should i do in sonar-scanner case?